# How do I sum then group by in a subquery?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, subquery

I have the following

```
SELECT
ticketNum, 
name,
id,
created
```

Which prints

| ticketNum | name | id | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | andy | 1 | 2021-07-02 10:58:54.476 UTC |
| abc | bob | 1 | 2021-07-02 10:58:54.476 UTC |
| abc | andy | 1 | 2021-07-02 10:58:54.476 UTC |
| abc | charlie | 1 | 2021-07-02 10:58:54.476 UTC |

I want to return the sum of ticketNum for each person and day so desired result:

| Name | Sum of TicketNum | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| andy | 2 | 2021-07-02 |
| bob | 1 | 2021-07-02 |
| charlie | 1 | 2021-07-02 |

I thought maybe I start with something like the following but I don't think I'm understanding it correctly.

```
SELECT 
name,
(SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT ticketNum)
    FROM mytable
    WHERE name = name
)
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  `ticketNum` VARCHAR(3),
  `name` VARCHAR(7),
  `id` INTEGER,
  `created` DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO my_table
  (`ticketNum`, `name`, `id`, `created`)
VALUES
  ('abc', 'andy', '1', '2021-07-02 10:58:54.476'),
  ('abc', 'bob', '1', '2021-07-02 10:58:54.476'),
  ('abc', 'andy', '1', '2021-07-02 10:58:54.476'),
  ('abc', 'charlie', '1', '2021-07-02 10:58:54.476');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    name Name,
    COUNT(ticketNum) 'Sum of TicketNum',
    MAX(created) as Date
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    name;
```

| Name | Sum of TicketNum | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| andy | 2 | 2021-07-02 10:58:54 |
| bob | 1 | 2021-07-02 10:58:54 |
| charlie | 1 | 2021-07-02 10:58:54 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mczvPhKewu79a5jgwUHARV/1)